# Retrieve multiple images from firebase in html static website

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

Can anyone help me in retrieving multiple images to my static website using javascript from firebase .Or i have to make a node js server ?

Comment: What did you try? Provide the sample source code which you tried but didn't work.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need a server to retrieve images from firebase.

First setup firebase storage from your firebase console add [firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) to your website.
Then in your javascript (in here you have an image named stars.jpg in images folder),

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var pathReference = storage.ref('images/stars.jpg');

storageRef.child('images/stars.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  // `url` is the download URL for 'images/stars.jpg'

  var img = document.getElementById('myimg');
  img.src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```